# Ruby RTP management

Tags: ruby, rtp

is there any gem that makes RTP(audio stream) management possible with Ruby?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `raop-client` gem is probably what you are looking for.

More info here [on tenderlove's blog](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2007/06/14/stream-to-your-airport-express-with-ruby/)